# How to create a big view (page) in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to MVC and learning some stuff of views, partial views etc.

I would like to make a simple page where lets consider "Login" and "Register" both comes together.
**Like facebook.**

I have found all the examples which is all having one view on page. I guess, to make a big view (complete page) we need to have partical views to use in one big view.

unfortunately, i am not able to find perfect example, may be lake of searching power or exact term to use for MVC.

I want to make a page where many partial views use in one big view and create a big page.

Can any one please help me to get video link or help link which can be useful and how exactly it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the partial views in

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-views&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Using @Html.Partial is fairly easy, I generally prefer @Html.Action to render another controllers action method in line, and it makes more sense for me in a situation like you mentioned above.

Something else to consider are the ajax type dialogs for login, now in the mvc4 developer preview templates at: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: I tend to think Partials are for stuff related to the model in some way where as render action is more for generic things like accounts, messaging etc

Comment: Perfect Adam, I am looking for this, even nop-commerce (i just check) is also work on the way you suggest

Comment: @DanielPowell true, (Im not sure if we're agreeing here on the post or not ha) but a registration model and a login model would be two separate models hence the use of Html.Action.